# Help with the meaning of Eric Schmidt's speech

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could you please check my rephrase to make sure if I get the speech right?

> You now see so many strong tech platforms coming, and you are seeing a
>   reordering and a future reordering of dominance or leaders or whatever
>   term you want to use because of the rise of the apps on the
>   smartphone.
>
> All bets are off at this point as to what the smartphone app infrastructure is going to look like' as a 'whole new set' of players
>   emerges to power smartphones, which are nothing but super-computers,
>   the Google chairman argued.

Here is my try:

You  can see now that many new tech companies has been created, and you have been seeing or you can see  the change and a POSSIBLE ( *for future*) change of giant dominant firms or leaders or whatever
 term you want to use because of the rise of the apps on the
 smartphone.

All predictions on how the future of smartphone apps will be is not clear or unknown these days yet, because "completely new technology firms start up to flourish smartphones which are considered as new super-computers

( Does he mean new firms will play a key role and change the balance of power in the world of new tech)

---

And can I ask what the difference is among these sentences below in the sense in the first paragrahp.

> You see a reordering.
>
> You are seeing a reordering.
>
> You  have been seeing a reordering.

http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2922460/Google-s-Eric-Schmidt-claims-internet-disappear-life-gets-connected-says-robots-WON-T-world.html

Comment: Rather than rewrite the entire paragraph, indicate which parts of the oroginal you think are ungrammatical. After that, rewrite with the phrases as you would write them (again highlight what you changed). In your question, there are too many changes to answer to without this becoming a proofreading exercise.

Comment: well I edited my question.I think it will be enough for me if you check my rephares.

Comment: Actually that is proofreading, which is OT here.

Comment: I believe Murat is asking for help understanding a very complex and confusing English speech.  We're not proofing Murat's work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This speech is confusing because the speaker has combined many ideas into a few sentences.  It becomes less confusing if we split up the ideas:

> You now see so many strong tech platforms coming [out].
>
> You are seeing a reordering of dominance [among industry leaders].
>
> And also a future reordering of dominance [among industry leaders].
>
> This is because of the rise of the apps on the smartphone.

When he speaks about tech platforms, he is speaking about devices.  The home computer, smartphone, game console, and laptop computer are all examples of platforms.  When he talks about strong platforms coming, he is talking about how smartphones and other devices are changing his industry.

When he says "dominance or leaders or whatever term you want to use", he is trying to discuss the industry leaders, those who dominate the industry.  He first says dominance, which is a very aggressive term for someone who is winning a competition.  He then changes that to leaders, a much more positive term for someone who is at the front of change. He then changes again to "whatever term you want to use", asking the listener to use their judgement to infer his meaning without adding the negative connotations of dominate or the positive connotations of leaders.  We can substitute "dominance among industry leaders" to incorporate both ideas.

When he talks about reordering among those who have dominance among industry leaders, he is suggesting big changes will make new people more dominant in the industry and make existing dominant leaders less significant.  He repeats this idea as "future reordering" to say that it will happen repeatedly, and the new leaders may be unseated.

He attributes these changes to smartphone apps.

> All bets are off at this point.
>
> [There is no way of knowing] what the smartphone app infrastructure is going to look like
>
> a 'whole new set' of players emerges to power smartphones,
>
> The Google chairman argued [smartphones] are nothing but super-computers.

Again, he is combining a lot of ideas.

"All bets are off" is from gambling, where people place bets with the house on the outcome of an event.  If the event changes dramatically, (For instance, one boxer is changed for a substitute) the house may cancel bets, offering refunds instead of honoring the wager.  To say "all bets are off" means that there is no way to estimate the odds of the outcome because the future has become so uncertain.

There is no way of knowing what the smartphone infrastructure will look like, because the industry is changing so quickly.

The new set of players are the people who will change the industry by "powering" cellphones, adding value with hardware and software.

The chairman believes that smartphones are "nothing but" (that is, absolutely) "super-computers", meaning that they have features beyond what a normal computer is capable of.

Comment: So, Mike Kozar explained very well, in detail. But you got the gist of it correctly in your question. Your grammar was not so great, and I think you meant "furnish" rather than "flourish", but you had the sense of it.  As for tense, the speaker used "are seeing" (present progressive) to indicate the changes are continuing now. This makes sense, as in the next sentence he says he expects continued change in the future.

Comment: @Mike Kozar Hi Mike!Thank you so much.This answer couldn't be better.I am extra happy because now I understand that I had got the gist of the speech, which you defined as a very complex and confusing.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Thank you so much.Your answer helped also.Thank you for the feedbacks.When it comes to the word "flourish", actually I used it deliberately.But I used it in wrong way unintentionally.Now I think I know my mistake that the word "flourish" is not a transitive word.But I used it in this way which I meant that new tech companies "support" or "help" to develop the smart phone app industry.So I think the app industry can "flourish"  but not " to be flourished by new firms" grammatically. Am I right?